# Are there any bounties that you can only do once?

Tags: destiny

I've noticed a few bounties that have been available multiple times, such as the 100 headshot kills bounty. I haven't seen any of the area-specific ones reappear, like the ones where you need to do 6 patrols on a certain planet. Are all bounties eventually available to redo, or are some only available once?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all bounties are repeatable and can reappear again. It just depends on what RNG chooses for that 24 hour period (It restocks at 4AM EST.). I'm not sure if they are different between platform, but I do know that everyone on the same platform gets to pick from the same bounties. Xb1 gets patrols and assassination targets pretty often.

Comment: Everyone on the platform gets the exact same bounties? I thought the bounties that were available to me matched my level/progress: first there were Earth bounties, then moon ones, and now I have some for the other planets available. It's possible that I got all of these progressive bounties from "bounty lead" messages, but that begs another question: are the bounties you get from messages repeatable?

Comment: Hm, yeah I'm not really sure how it works in terms of progression, but I do know that at "end-game" they are all the same because my friends and I all work together on the same bounties for the day. The bounty leads may be part of that progression as they are one of the "new" bounties that get added.

Comment: There is some difference based on what's available but sometimes it doesn't work. For example I got a mars patrol bounty waaaay before I could go there. There are also some bounty-exchange things that you get at your mailbox after certain story events.